# SSL with appcloud.net subdomains

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

My SSL certificate is not verified on a subdomain of cloudapp.net - Classic Virtual server at Azure.

I setup everything in my IIS, and my port rule 443.

Could the subdomains at cloudapp.net not work with HTTPS at all?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: Since you use IIS on your side, why did you add azure-web-sites tag to your thread? For your question, are you the owner of  appcloud.net domain? By searching the domain, I found it is on sale.

Comment: @Amor sorry, i was talking about cloudapp.net - azure virtual servers domain. And that's why I'm tagging Azure

Comment: Did you use Azure Virtual Machine or Azure Cloud Service to host your web application?

Comment: @Amor Azure Virtual Machine, and i wanted to access the subdomain on cloudapp.net directly, without using a custom domain. But i can't seem to make the certificate be verified at all

Answer (score 1):

> Could the subdomains at cloudapp.net not work with HTTPS at all?

I tested it recently on my side and I make sure that the subdomains at cloudapp.net could work with HTTPS. Following are my steps.

Step 1. Generated certificate and installed it to IIS. I created and used a self-signed certificate for testing. I generated the .pfx file according to ways described in following link.

[Generating a Self-Signed Certificate for Windows Azure Cloud Service](https://schen1628.wordpress.com/2013/09/12/generating-a-self-signed-certificate-for-windows-azure-cloud-service/)

After that, we can upload the certificate to IIS of VM.

[image]

Step 2. Add HTTPS binding to your IIS.

[image]

Step 3. Enable 443 port for inbound rules and outbound rules.

[image]

Step 4. Add 443 endpoint for your VM.

[image]

Comment: Amor, Thanks for putting so much time into this. But i still get the red unsecured flag. I followed the steps 1 by 1 tens of times to make sure I'm not missing anything, still the self signed certificate is not working. It doesn't work even from my localhost inside the server, so you can rule out firewall problems

Comment: The red unsecured flag means the certificate is not a trusted certificate. You can just ignore this or acquire an SSL certificate from a [trusted certificate authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Certificate_authority).

Comment: I tried that as well, but my certificate was not approved obviously, because i don't own the domain cloudapp.net ( I wish :) ) That was my first initial question actually, If i can set a trusted certificate on this domain..

Comment: That is the restrict of cloudapp.net. Please also check this thread. [Does Azure offer https for “cloudapp.net”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20494005/does-azure-offer-https-for-cloudapp-net). We can't add trust certificate to sub domain of cloudapp.net currently. Please use a custom domain instead.

Comment: thank you for your help. Those where my thoughts as well after trying every possible solution :)